# Is there a way to copy a "floating picture" in a specific range and paste it to different sheet with VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

Please refer to the above image for better understanding of my question.

I tried to select the range, copy it and paste it to different sheet but the picture never follows it.

Is there a way to copy a "floating picture" in a specific range and paste it to different sheet with VBA?

Comment: Do you know the picture's `Name` ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent the picture name will be random so no :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just refer to the Picture's `TopLeftCell` Property:

```
Sub PictureMover()
    Dim s As Shape
    For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        sAddy = s.TopLeftCell.Address(0, 0)
        If sAddy = "A7" Or sAddy = "A8" Then
            s.Copy
            Sheets("Sheet2").Paste
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```